# Adding a "rate my app" button in libgdx game

Tags: android, libgdx

I want add a button in my game that will open up an URL to my app in Play Store. Below is what I got so far, but when I click on rate button it does not open the respective URL.

My rate code is:

```
if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){
    guiCam.unproject(touchPoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.input.getY(), 0));

    if(OverlapTester.pointInRectangle(rateButtonBound, touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)){
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shagunstudios.racinggame");
        }
        catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.println(e1);
        }

        if(Settings.soundEnabled)
            Assets.click_sound.play(1.0f);

        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should really be using [openURI](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Net.html#openURI(java.lang.String)) method in the Net module.

Something like:

```
Gdx.net.openURI("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shagunstudios.racinggame");
```

`exec` is probably not cross platform and will not work on Android at the least. 
Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Wanna provide some more details?

Comment: Uhm now is working, i don't know why i used to get crash before

Comment: @BoldijarPaul You might have forgot to provide Internet Access Permissions in Android Manifest file

Comment: Gdx.net.openURI is working very slow for me. Once a click the button, it goes to playstore after 3 sec and in that 3 sec time period nothing happens and user will feel doubtful then once it goes to playstore , the playstore also seems to do many calculations as playstore also becomes very slow. I see a white screen for 3 sec and then the page for my game appears. Any Idea?

Comment: @SagarBalyan is the device slow? The implementation for that function is extremely simple. I assume you are on Android.
See source:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidNet.java

Answer (score 1):

Put a method containing code like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/whateveryoururlis"));
this.startActivity(i);
```

in your Android back end (in the class that extends the Libgdx `AndroidApplication`).  Then expose that method to your platform independent Libgdx code using an interface (and provide place holder implementations on your other backends).  See https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ApplicationPlatformSpecific for details.

Comment: Alternatively, you can call [openURI](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Net.html#openURI(java.lang.String))
which actually does the identical thing in Android backend implementation if you look at the [source](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidNet.java).